# get database metadata using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I need to get column names from a table, I referred this link here: http://www.kodejava.org/examples/163.html

It shows using jdbc to get the metadata, I want to know is there any hibernate method similar to this? I am having mysql and oracle as the databases.

Comment: Hibernate needs you to hardcode the table and column names in order to map the entities. Why would you want to get them dynamically? Just hardcode them once more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following codes:

```
String[] columnNames = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(Java.class).getPropertyNames();

Type[] columnTypes = sessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Java.class).getPropertyTypes();
```

Comment: its very useful. Thank you Kamiel

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] columnNames = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Employee.class).getPropertyNames();

org.hibernate.type.Type[] columnTypes = getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Employee.class).getPropertyTypes();
```