# How to get the All table metadata in spring boot - JPA - hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I need to get META information of **All the tables present in my schema dynamically** , Meta infos are such as table , entity ,column name etc.

I have followed the following tutorial

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-get-the-entity-mapping-to-database-table-binding-metadata-from-hibernate/

as said in the above link i have created the Integrator called MetadataExtractorIntegrator.java

```
package com.test.ttv;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
import org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry;

public class MetadataExtractorIntegrator implements org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator {

    public static final MetadataExtractorIntegrator INSTANCE = new MetadataExtractorIntegrator();

    private Database database;

    private Metadata metadata;

    public Database getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }

    public Metadata getMetadata() {
        return metadata;
    }

    @Override
    public void integrate(
            Metadata metadata,
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

        this.database = metadata.getDatabase();
        this.metadata = metadata;

    }

    @Override
    public void disintegrate(
        SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
        SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

    }
}
```

And trying to register it in my application by following config

application.yml

```
jpa:
  properties:
    hibernate.integrator_provider: com.test.ttv.MetadataExtractorIntegrator
```

And i am getting the following Exception while Starting the build

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.IntegratorProvider
```

More StackTrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.IntegratorProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1085) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:858) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
        at testtest(Test.java:31) [main/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.IntegratorProvider
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildBootstrapServiceRegistry(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:339) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:196) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.14.Final.jar:5.2.14.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:51) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:388) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
        ... 16 common frames omitted
```

Could anyone help me to solve this issue?? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get database metadata using hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8795321/get-database-metadata-using-hibernate)

Comment: Both are different, here i need to know all the tables meta info, unlike there they need to get the field info by passing table name

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Spring Boot, `spring.jpa.properties` points to a [`Map<String, String>`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ab19db19a3d05e3135a1d38cb3a3680351b5d427/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/JpaProperties.java#L45), so it can only contain `String` values.

However in Hibernate, when the [EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/ea77c1fb4b65905622e2ab74211c232e6dcac9b2/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/jpa/boot/internal/EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java#L388) reads `hibernate.integrator_provider` it expects to find an instance of `IntegratorProvider` and not a Class name, hence the exception.

You can however add a bean that implements `HibernatePropertiesCustomizer` to add the `IntegrationProvider` instance to the Hibernate properties:

```
@Component
public class HibernateConfig implements HibernatePropertiesCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(Map<String, Object> hibernateProperties) {
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.integrator_provider",
                (IntegratorProvider) () -> Collections.singletonList(MetadataExtractorIntegrator.INSTANCE));
    }
}
```

I have created a working example in [this repository](https://github.com/andyrbell/hibernate-properties-customizer-example).

Comment: Wow! Thanks lot!

Comment: The class HibernatePropertiesCustomizer is implemented starting from spring boot 2.0.0. Still looking for a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: For earlier versions or a more idiomatic approach in Spring, set the `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integrator_provider` to the class name of a class implementing the `IntegratorProvider` (a class name works, the problem of the OP was that he used the name of the `Integrator` instead of an `IntegratorProvider`). You can also see that explained here: https://vladmihalcea.com/dto-projection-jpa-query/

Answer (score 1):

In `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean`, there is a variable argument setter method for `hibernateIntegrators` which will accept one or more instances of `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator`

So in `org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean` configuration add the below property

```
<property name="hibernateIntegrators" ref="metadataExtractorIntegrator" />
```

and make the `Integrator` as managed bean

```
    package com.test.ttv;
    import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
    import org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database;
    import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor;
    import org.hibernate.service.spi.SessionFactoryServiceRegistry;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

    @Component  
    public class MetadataExtractorIntegrator implements org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator {

        private Database database;

        private Metadata metadata;

        public Database getDatabase() {
            return database;
        }

        public Metadata getMetadata() {
            return metadata;
        }

        @Override
        public void integrate(
                Metadata metadata,
                SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
                SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

            this.database = metadata.getDatabase();
            this.metadata = metadata;

        }

        @Override
        public void disintegrate(
            SessionFactoryImplementor sessionFactory,
            SessionFactoryServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Springboot 1.5.x, The "HibernatePropertiesCustomizer" is not exist.

I found a solution usable from [here](https://techblog.bozho.net/spring-managed-hibernate-event-listeners/). You can not use integrator here, but you can add all the event listeners one by one. below is my code code:

```
public class RootAwareInsertEventListener implements PersistEventListener {

    public static final RootAwareInsertEventListener INSTANCE = new RootAwareInsertEventListener();

    @Override
    public void onPersist(PersistEvent event) throws HibernateException {
        final Object entity = event.getObject();

        if (entity instanceof RootAware) {
            RootAware rootAware = (RootAware) entity;
            Object root = rootAware.getRoot();
            event.getSession().lock(root, LockMode.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);

            log.info("Incrementing {} entity version because a {} child entity has been inserted",
                    root, entity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPersist(PersistEvent event, Map createdAlready)
            throws HibernateException {
        onPersist(event);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class HibernateListenerConfigurer {

    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        SessionFactoryImpl sessionFactory = emf.unwrap(SessionFactoryImpl.class);
        EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.PERSIST).appendListener(RootAwareInsertEventListener.INSTANCE);
        registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.FLUSH_ENTITY).appendListener(RootAwareUpdateAndDeleteEventListener.INSTANCE);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, that op using `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integrator_provider` property were providing `org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator` implementation class instead of `org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.IntegratorProvider` implementation - which is desired here by `EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl` - at least in hibernate in version `5.4.32` that I'm using.

```
private void applyIntegrationProvider(Map integrationSettings, BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder bsrBuilder) {
        Object integrationSetting = integrationSettings.get( INTEGRATOR_PROVIDER );
        if ( integrationSetting == null ) {
            return;
        }
        final IntegratorProvider integratorProvider = loadSettingInstance(
                INTEGRATOR_PROVIDER,
                integrationSetting,
                IntegratorProvider.class
        );

        if ( integratorProvider != null ) {
            for ( Integrator integrator : integratorProvider.getIntegrators() ) {
                bsrBuilder.applyIntegrator( integrator );
            }
        }
    }
```

All you need is an implementation of `org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.IntegratorProvider` which will return apropriate integrator instance/s:

```
package com.levitatingapes.hibernate;

import org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator;
import org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.IntegratorProvider;

public class HibernateIntegratorProvider implements IntegratorProvider {
    @Override
    public List<Integrator> getIntegrators() {
        return List.of(new RootAwareEventListenerIntegrator());
    }
}
```

and then pass class name from above to property as following:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.integrator_provider=com.levitatingapes.hibernate.HibernateIntegratorProvider
```